# How to lock the color when u selected it and save to database which is when refresh the page the selected color gone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What i want to ask is after selected the situation in the drop down list how to lock the color and save into database?

code for javascript and jquery for locking the color from the drop down list and save to database

This is the code for the table while same with mine Similar to http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eQNp5/1/

HTML Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><select name="Select2">
    <option></option>
    <option>Approved</option>
    <option>Pending</option>
    <option>Disapproved</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><select name="Select2">
    <option></option>
    <option>Approved</option>
    <option>Pending</option>
    <option>Disapproved</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><select name="Select3">
    <option></option>
    <option>Approved</option>
    <option>Pending</option>
    <option>Disapproved</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
```

javascript:

[java script code use picture because of cannot paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIOyt.png)

Table pic:
[table pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzQux.png)
after refresh all gone how to lock it

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution what you looking for.
For lock the color, you can disable the select field when it selected once by writing this,

```
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
```

And for save it to database, You can use jquery ajax. The whole javascript and jquery code is given bellow.

```
var color = ['none', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
    $('select').change(function() {
        var colorCode=color[$(':selected', this).index()];
        $(this).parents('tr').css('background', colorCode);

        //For Lock The Select Option
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);

        //Save It To Database
        $.ajax({url: "saveColor.php?colorCode="+colorCode, success: function(result){
          
          //If there is all ok on saveColor.php, then you can show success message here
          /*...*/
          //console.log(result);

        }});    
    });
```

Now if you have saveColor.php then you can get the color code in $_GET['colorCode'] on it. Then save it to database with you php code.

Comment: With mean //For Lock The Select Option
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);  after adding this code and select the color and it will lock it after refresh?

Comment: This will lock the select option field as user cannot change it after. Is this you mean that how to lock the color or what?

Comment: Yes so after adding the code the select option will lock the color right? but after adding the code and i choose color. After refresh the color gone

Comment: For this case, after refresh the page you should have to retrieve the saved color form database and put it on the <tr> background color. like this,<tr style="background-color:<?php echo $colorCode; ?>"> . You have to write a bunch of php code before.

Comment: for example  when i select first options and the row will show red color and i want to lock the red color which when i open the website again the row still maintain on red color

Answer (score 0):

as your question as not clear but you already tag php and jquery...

so you want to store the color inside you database after select.use jquery ajax.

```
var color = ['none', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
$('select').change(function() {
   var row = $(this).parents('tr'),
       selectedColor = color[$(':selected', this).index()];    

    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      data: {color: selectedColor},
      url: 'page_to_php.php'
   }).done(function(data){
       row.css('background', selectedColor);
   }).fail(function(err){
      console.log(err);
   })
});
```

in server side page_to_php.php

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
   $color = $_POST['color'];

  // now you can process your color to database.

}
```